# Solve the following trigonometric exercise...

Tags: trigonometry

Can you please give a hint how to solve this exercise:

$$\log(\tan 22)+ \log(\tan 68)=?\\
\tan22\cdot\tan68=?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Another hint: for this problem in particular you could have worked it out numerically with a calculator; that's not sufficient to give a *justification* for the answer but the justification is easier to come up with if you know the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's a good hint but imagine I have an exam and don't have a calculator:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** In degree
$$\tan(90-x)=\frac{1}{\tan x}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$22^\circ=90^\circ-68^\circ$$ and $$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x$$

also $$\tan22^\circ\cdot\tan68^\circ\ne0$$